# Apache redirect to https and modify url structure

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

Goal:

Redirect from http://example.com/library/page123.htm

to http**s**://example.com/library/**folder**/page123.htm

I have found plenty of example on how to perform redirects to ssl and how to add folders, but am struggling to execute these together. Additionally, there are multiple pages under the "library" folder of the old url structure.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: The following seemed to make sense to me but it's clearly not working since it takes the entire https site down.   `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/library/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/library/folder$1 [R,L]`